# Drawable padding doesn't work

Tags: android, android-drawable

I've got the following xml:

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/searchQuery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:drawablePadding="25dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_black_18dp"
                android:ems="8"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text" />
```

I want to make icon move, but `drawablePadding` has no effect. What is wrong?

Comment: How exactly you'd like to move icon? `drawablePadding` should change distance between text and icon only (according to docs) and not the distance between icon and edges of the view (for that there is `padding` options)

Comment: I'd like to change distance between icon and edge

Comment: Then try to use `android:paddingBottom` or Top/Right/Left

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`drawablePadding` is padding between the drawable and rest of your widget.
use `padding` attribute to provide padding around your widget including drawable.
[image: drawable]

Answer (score -1):

According to your code, you are giving static height to your AutoCompleteTextView i.e. 30dp. That's the reason the drawable padding is not visible.
Try using wrap content if you want drawable padding visible.

Comment: Height has nothing related to drawablePadding in this case. Icon is to the right of the text (`drawableRight`), so drawablePadding can only increase width (but actually width will not be increased, because of `match_parent` – it already has max width), but not height.

Answer (score -1):

`drawablePadding` only take effect when the widget view size is small enough.

For `drawableRight` and `drawableLeft`, `drawablePdding` only works when the view's width is `wrap_content`.

If the view's width is `match_parent` or it has a specific big value for width or minWidth, the drawable will be sitting on the edge.

For the layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/red_dot_indicator"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/red_dot_indicator"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello World! 2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/red_dot_indicator"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Hello World! 3" />
```

The screenshot is like:
[image]